# autostart ppp connection when vlan comes up

Tags: debian, linux-networking, pppoe

I want to start a ppp connection on my router on startup, but i need to have a vlan activated before. 
The problem is that if i ifup the vlan in the ppp interface, the vlan is not up when pppoe tries to connect.

this is how my /etc/network/interfaces looks like:

```
auto myprovider
iface myprovider inet ppp
        pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0.2 up
        provider myprovider

auto eth0.2
iface eth0.2 inet manual
```

The ppp device is phyiscaly located on eth0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if also the physical interface is set to auto:

```
auto eth0
auto eth0.2
auto myprovider

iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth0.2 inet manual

iface myprovider inet ppp
        pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0.2 up
        provider myprovider
```